# Group By expression in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle12c, oracle19c

I am installing a database schema in Oracle 19c, and the installation scripts have been used repeatedly in Oracle 12 without problems.

My problem with 19c is when it runs our views script, it throws an on at some of views. The error we are seeing the not a group by expression.

We have a few views where for example we have something like this:

```
SELECT name, TRUNC(date) as Day
FROM sometable
GROUP BY name, TRUNC(date)
```

It is pointing the error at the select as though it doesn't see that the field is already in the group by expression.

As said, these queries work fine in Oracle 12 for years, it is only now when moving to 19 that we are seeing problems.

Is this a bug in 19c or does something need to be applied?

Comment: Shouldn't the second `TRUNC(date)` be `Day`?

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example of the problem?  I'm not seeing the query you posted fail for me.

Comment: I have never known an alias to be added to a group by expression before. Does that sound right to me

Comment: The example given is exactly it but view will not install on oracle19c

Comment: The example given can't be exactly what you're doing-- `date` isn't a valid column name.  And you presumably have a `create view` somewhere.  Making my best guess at what you are actually doing, I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue on 19c https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/mzgjcgjrs4n3t9ml063sk78rc  Hence, it would be helpful if you could include a reproducible example in your question.  A link to a liveSQL session (or some other fiddle) that demonstrates the issue would be very, very helpful.

Comment: where is an aggregation function like sum()? a group by must contain the aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

19c, you say? Can't reproduce it.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Table you used (so that you wouldn't say that this is the culprit) (obviously, `date` is an invalid column name; that's reserved for the `date` datatype).

```
SQL> create table sometable as
  2    select 'Little' name, sysdate datum
  3    from dual
  4    connect by level <= 3;

Table created.
```

Does query itself work? Yes:

```
SQL> select name, trunc(datum) as day
  2  from sometable
  3  group by name, trunc(datum);

NAME   DAY
------ --------
Little 26.01.22
```

Note that - as you aren't aggregating anything - you could have used `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SQL> select DISTINCT name, trunc(datum) as day
  2  from sometable;

NAME   DAY
------ --------
Little 26.01.22
```

Can I create a view? Yes:

```
SQL> create view v_sometable as
  2  select name, trunc(datum) as day
  3  from sometable
  4  group by name, trunc(datum);

View created.

SQL>
```

As I said, I can't reproduce it.

---

Please, copy/paste your own SQL*Plus session (just like I did) so that we'd see what **exactly** you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in 19c

Comment: How is it a bug in 19c? I tested it on 19c (didn't you see the BANNER info?).

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2726182_1.html suggest you read this. We have applied the fix and our problem has gone away

Comment: Aha, I see. Looks like the keyword here is **upgrade**. I didn't upgrade anything, I ran that query in a newly installed 19c - that's why I didn't get any errors. OK then, thank you for letting us know, I'm glad you fixed it (one way or another).

Comment: @Andy5 just wondering what the support oracle fix say? im unable to access it and im running into the same issue

Comment: I hope I am not violating Oracle terms & conditions by saying that one of its suggestions is to upgrade to 19.16 where the bug is fixed. If you search for `oracle 31504723 8528517` you may find sites that repeat the contents of the support note.